# Accessing variable in render in Reactjs and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm storing data fetched from mongodb through nodejs in a variable like this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
    .then(res=>{
     Userdata=res.data.users
      console.log(Userdata)
      console.log(Userdata._id)
       
    })
```

But I'm unable to access the data in variable in render function here:

```
if(this.state.loggedin){
  
      return <Redirect to={`/UI/Navbar/Dashboard/${Userdata._id}`}/>
    }
```

it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

Comment: `Userdata=res.data.users` will occur _after_ your render function runs.

Comment: What does `console.log(Userdata)` give ?

Comment: The if statement is used in render function but I can't access the data stored in Userdata when redirecting it

Comment: console.log(Userdata) shows the data stored in json form Userdata variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Both chunks are asynchronous. It is better to wrap async data load with `useEffect`, explicitly set the state of some top-level component, and propagate logged in user with Context API down to other components.

Answer (score 0):

Your render function tries to create a component in spite of the data is noe fetched yet. Thats why it Userdata is undefined.
Your Userdata must be a state, when axios has fired, use setState to change Userdata.
While Userdata is fetching you have to render something like 'in process...'

Comment: what type of state the variable should be?

Comment: I have tried setting the Userdata in a state but it still does not work

Comment: Userdate must be the same type as what res.data.users returns. I assume it is an array, so you cn set initial state as an empty one []. As for it still does not work - the snippet you show is not enough to find the problem.